# How to convert java CharSequence to c++ char* through JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, charsequence

I feel that this should have a simple answer as I can do it easily with a java `String`, but something is going wrong with the `CharSequence`. My java code initializes a `cppGenerator`, passes a `functionBlock object` to its `generateImplementation method`, and returns a `CharSequence`. Here is my code:

```
jobject fBlock = env->CallObjectMethod(structuredTextModel, getFunction);
jclass CPPGenerator = lookForClass(env, "Path/CPPGenerator");
jobject CPPGeneratorImpl = invokeClassObj(env, CPPGenerator);
    jmethodID generateImplementation = env->GetMethodID(CPPGenerator, "generateImplementation", "(LPath/FunctionBlock;)Ljava/lang/CharSequence;");
jobject mid = env->CallObjectMethod(CPPGeneratorImpl, generateImplementation, fBlock);
jstring jresult = (jstring)mid;
char* result = (char*)env->GetStringUTFChars(jresult, 0);
```

This logic has worked for me when using `String` but this function returns a `CharSequence`. No classes, objects, or methods are returning null. The program crashes in `jni.h` attempting to call `GetStringUTFChars`. So i know I cannot use this method for CharSequence. Is there just a jni method I am missing or do I have to do something completely different for a CharSequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just cast `mid` to `jstring` and call `GetStringUTFChars` (since `mid` might not be a `String`, which seems to be the case). There is no convenience method like `GetStringUTFChars` for `CharSequence`s like there is for `String`s.

You'd have to do it the inconvenient way of calling `charAt`:

```
jclass cCharSequence = env->FindClass("java/lang/CharSequence");
jmethodID mLength = env->GetMethodID(cCharSequence, "length", "()I");
jmethodID mCharAt = env->GetMethodID(cCharSequence, "charAt", "(I)C");

int length = env->CallIntMethod(mid, mLength);
std::string str;
str.reserve(length);
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    str += env->CallCharMethod(mid, mCharAt, i);
}

// use 'str.c_str()'...
```

Comment: ahah, charAt. That's what I was looking for. I figured I would have to do something like this if there was no method built in. Thank you this works perfectly for my code.

Comment: Are you sure you don't get a warning here: jchar is wider than char? In any case, narrowing is both lossless and accurate only if the target character set is ASCII or ISO 8859-1. You could use `std::wstring` to stay with UTF-16 (jchar).

Comment: @TomBlodget I had forgotten about that fact. But having a compatible encoding is a pre-condition for using `GetStringUTFChars` any ways, so this should still be a correct equivalent.

Comment: Yes surely the question asker should know what they are doing but GetStringUTFChars will result in valid _modified_ UTF-8 for all CharSequences (UTF-16), without lost or garbage data.

Comment: @TravisHerbert: Why not convert the `CharSequence` to a `String` using [`CharSequence::toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#toString())? Then you can use `String::GetStringUTFChars()` as before.  Yes, it uses more memory, but it also avoids any issues with lossy data conversions. Using `CharSequence::charAt()` with `std::string` is lossy for non-ASCII characters (and yes, that includes ISO-8859-1). Any character > #127 is at risk.

Comment: @TomBlodget: `std::wstring` uses UTF-16 only on Windows, it uses UTF-32 on other platforms. This is why `wchar_t` is not a portable data type for Unicode handling. You can use `std::basic_string<jchar>` or C++11's `std::u16string` to assure a UTF-16 string on all platforms. Or use C++11's `std::wstring_convert` to convert UTF-16 input to `std::wstring` in its native format

Comment: @TomBlodget Yes i tested the code and it works properly. And the encoding will be consistent.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I may suggest converting to a string to the people working on the java side. There is however a small range of characters legal to be passed into these functions anyways and would result in an error within the java side before being called by the c++, so I am not worried about non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @TravisHerbert: Could you post a reference to such character set, please:
_"a small range of characters legal to be passed into these functions anyways and would result in an error within the java side"_

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `toString` directly?

```
jclass clzCharSequence = env->GetObjectClass(mid);
jmethodID toString = env->GetMethodID(clzCharSequence, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
jobject s = env->CallObjectMethod(mid, toString);
const char* cstr = env->GetStringUTFChars(static_cast<jstring>(s), NULL);
// do something with cstr
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(static_cast<jstring>(s), cstr);
```